# Bacula windows client could not connect to Bacula director

Tags: windows, bacula

I have a Bacula server on my Linux Debian squeeze host (Bacula version 5.0.2) and a Bacula client on Windows XP SP3.

On my network each client can see each other, can share files and can ping.

On my local server I could run `bconsole` and the server responds but when I run `bconsole` or bat on my windows client the server does not respond.

Here are my configuration files:

**bacula-dir.conf**:

```
#
# Default Bacula Director Configuration file
#
#  The only thing that MUST be changed is to add one or more
#   file or directory names in the Include directive of the
#   FileSet resource.
#
#  For Bacula release 5.0.2 (28 April 2010) -- debian squeeze/sid
#
#  You might also want to change the default email address
#   from root to your address.  See the "mail" and "operator"
#   directives in the Messages resource.
#

Director {                            # define myself   Name =
nima-desktop-dir   DIRport = 9101                # where we listen for
UA connections   QueryFile = "/etc/bacula/scripts/query.sql"  
WorkingDirectory = "/var/lib/bacula"   PidDirectory =
"/var/run/bacula"   Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 1   Password =
"Cv70F6pf1t6pBopT4vQOnigDrR0v3L"         # Console password   Messages
= Daemon   DirAddress = 127.0.0.1  # DirAddress = 72.16.208.1 }

JobDefs {   Name = "DefaultJob"   Type = Backup   Level = Incremental 
Client = nima-desktop-fd    FileSet = "Full Set"   Schedule =
"WeeklyCycle"   Storage = File   Messages = Standard   Pool = File  
Priority = 10   Write Bootstrap = "/var/lib/bacula/%c.bsr" }


#
# Define the main nightly save backup job
#   By default, this job will back up to disk in /nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir Job {   Name = "BackupClient1"  
JobDefs = "DefaultJob" }

#Job {
#  Name = "BackupClient2"
#  Client = nima-desktop2-fd
#  JobDefs = "DefaultJob"
#}

# Backup the catalog database (after the nightly save) Job {   Name = "BackupCatalog"   JobDefs = "DefaultJob"   Level = Full  
FileSet="Catalog"   Schedule = "WeeklyCycleAfterBackup"   # This
creates an ASCII copy of the catalog   # Arguments to
make_catalog_backup.pl are:   #  make_catalog_backup.pl <catalog-name>
RunBeforeJob = "/etc/bacula/scripts/make_catalog_backup.pl MyCatalog" 
# This deletes the copy of the catalog   RunAfterJob  = "/etc/bacula/scripts/delete_catalog_backup"   Write Bootstrap =
"/var/lib/bacula/%n.bsr"   Priority = 11                   # run after
main backup }

#
# Standard Restore template, to be changed by Console program
#  Only one such job is needed for all Jobs/Clients/Storage ...
# Job {   Name = "RestoreFiles"   Type = Restore   Client=nima-desktop-fd                    FileSet="Full Set"          
Storage = File                         Pool = Default   Messages =
Standard   Where =
/nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir/bacula-restores }

# job for vmware windows host  Job { Name = "nimaxp-fd"  Type = Backup Client = nimaxp-fd  FileSet = "nimaxp-fs"  Schedule = "WeeklyCycle"
Storage = File Messages = Standard Pool = Default Write Bootstrap =
"/var/bacula/working/rsys-win-www-1-fd.bsr" #Change this }

# job for vmware windows host  Job { Name = "arg-michael-fd"  Type = Backup Client = nimaxp-fd  FileSet = "arg-michael-fs"  Schedule =
"WeeklyCycle" Storage = File Messages = Standard Pool = Default Write
Bootstrap = "/var/bacula/working/rsys-win-www-1-fd.bsr" #Change this }

# List of files to be backed up FileSet {   Name = "Full Set"   Include {
   Options {
     signature = MD5
   }
#    
#  Put your list of files here, preceded by 'File =', one per line
#    or include an external list with:
#
#    File = <file-name
#
#  Note: / backs up everything on the root partition.
#    if you have other partitions such as /usr or /home
#    you will probably want to add them too.
#
#  By default this is defined to point to the Bacula binary
#    directory to give a reasonable FileSet to backup to
#    disk storage during initial testing.
#
   File = /usr/sbin   }

#
# If you backup the root directory, the following two excluded
#   files can be useful
#   Exclude {
   File = /var/lib/bacula
   File = /nonexistant/path/to/file/archive/dir
   File = /proc
   File = /tmp
   File = /.journal
   File = /.fsck   } }

# List of files to be backed up FileSet {   Name = "nimaxp-fs"   Enable VSS = yes   Include {
   Options {
     signature = MD5
   }
   File = "C:\softwares"
   File = C:/softwares
   File = "C:/softwares"   } }

# List of files to be backed up FileSet {   Name = "arg-michael-fs"   Enable VSS = yes   Include {
   Options {
     signature = MD5
   }
   File = "C:\softwares"
   File = C:/softwares
   File = "C:/softwares"   } }

#
# When to do the backups, full backup on first sunday of the month,
#  differential (i.e. incremental since full) every other sunday,
#  and incremental backups other days Schedule {   Name = "WeeklyCycle"   Run = Full 1st sun at 23:05   Run = Differential
2nd-5th sun at 23:05   Run = Incremental mon-sat at 23:05 }

# This schedule does the catalog. It starts after the WeeklyCycle Schedule {   Name = "WeeklyCycleAfterBackup"   Run = Full sun-sat at
23:10 }

# This is the backup of the catalog FileSet {   Name = "Catalog"   Include {
   Options {
     signature = MD5
   }
   File = "/var/lib/bacula/bacula.sql"   } }

# Client (File Services) to backup Client {   Name = nima-desktop-fd   Address = localhost   FDPort = 9102   Catalog = MyCatalog   Password =
"_MOfxEuRzxijc0DIMcBqtyx9iW1tzE7V6"          # password for FileDaemon
File Retention = 30 days            # 30 days   Job Retention = 6
months            # six months   AutoPrune = yes                     #
Prune expired Jobs/Files }
# Client  file service for vmware windows host Client {   Name = nimaxp-fd   Address = nimaxp   FDPort = 9102   Catalog = MyCatalog  
Password = "Ku8F1YAhDz5EMUQjiC9CcSw95Aho9XbXailUmjOaAXJP"      #
password for FileDaemon   File Retention = 30 days            # 30
days   Job Retention = 6 months            # six months   AutoPrune =
yes                     # Prune expired Jobs/Files }

# Client  file service for vmware windows host Client {   Name = arg-michael-fd   Address = 192.168.0.61   FDPort = 9102   Catalog =
MyCatalog   Password = "b4E9FU6s/9Zm4BVFFnbXVKhlyd/zWxj0oWITKK6CALR/" 
# password for FileDaemon   File Retention = 30 days            # 30 days   Job Retention = 6 months            # six months   AutoPrune =
yes                     # Prune expired Jobs/Files }

#
# Second Client (File Services) to backup
#  You should change Name, Address, and Password before using
#
#Client {
#  Name = nima-desktop2-fd                
#  Address = localhost2
#  FDPort = 9102
#  Catalog = MyCatalog
#  Password = "_MOfxEuRzxijc0DIMcBqtyx9iW1tzE7V62"         # password for FileDaemon 2
#  File Retention = 30 days            # 30 days
#  Job Retention = 6 months            # six months
#  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired Jobs/Files
#}


# Definition of file storage device Storage {   Name = File
# Do not use "localhost" here       Address = localhost                # N.B. Use a fully qualified name here   SDPort = 9103   Password = "Cj-gtxugC4dAymY01VTSlUgMTT5LFMHf9"   Device = FileStorage   Media
Type = File }



# Definition of DDS tape storage device
#Storage {
#  Name = DDS-4    
#  Do not use "localhost" here
#  Address = localhost                # N.B. Use a fully qualified name here
#  SDPort = 9103
#  Password = "Cj-gtxugC4dAymY01VTSlUgMTT5LFMHf9"          # password for Storage daemon
#  Device = DDS-4                      # must be same as Device in Storage daemon
#  Media Type = DDS-4                  # must be same as MediaType in Storage daemon
#  Autochanger = yes                   # enable for autochanger device
#}

# Definition of 8mm tape storage device
#Storage {
#  Name = "8mmDrive"
#  Do not use "localhost" here
#  Address = localhost                # N.B. Use a fully qualified name here
#  SDPort = 9103
#  Password = "Cj-gtxugC4dAymY01VTSlUgMTT5LFMHf9"
#  Device = "Exabyte 8mm"
#  MediaType = "8mm"
#}

# Definition of DVD storage device
#Storage {
#  Name = "DVD"
#  Do not use "localhost" here
#  Address = localhost                # N.B. Use a fully qualified name here
#  SDPort = 9103
#  Password = "Cj-gtxugC4dAymY01VTSlUgMTT5LFMHf9"
#  Device = "DVD Writer"
#  MediaType = "DVD"
#}


# Generic catalog service Catalog {   Name = MyCatalog
# Uncomment the following line if you want the dbi driver
# dbdriver = "dbi:sqlite3"; dbaddress = 127.0.0.1; dbport =     dbname = "bacula"; dbuser = ""; dbpassword = "" }

# Reasonable message delivery -- send most everything to email address
#  and to the console Messages {   Name = Standard
#
# NOTE! If you send to two email or more email addresses, you will need
#  to replace the %r in the from field (-f part) with a single valid
#  email address in both the mailcommand and the operatorcommand.
#  What this does is, it sets the email address that emails would display
#  in the FROM field, which is by default the same email as they're being
#  sent to.  However, if you send email to more than one address, then
#  you'll have to set the FROM address manually, to a single address. 
#  for example, a 'no-reply@mydomain.com', is better since that tends to
#  tell (most) people that its coming from an automated source.

#   mailcommand = "/usr/lib/bacula/bsmtp -h localhost -f \"\(Bacula\) \<%r\>\" -s \"Bacula: %t %e of %c %l\" %r"   operatorcommand =
"/usr/lib/bacula/bsmtp -h localhost -f \"\(Bacula\) \<%r\>\" -s
\"Bacula: Intervention needed for %j\" %r"   mail = root@localhost =
all, !skipped               operator = root@localhost = mount  
console = all, !skipped, !saved
#
# WARNING! the following will create a file that you must cycle from
#          time to time as it will grow indefinitely. However, it will
#          also keep all your messages if they scroll off the console.
#   append = "/var/lib/bacula/log" = all, !skipped   catalog = all }


#
# Message delivery for daemon messages (no job). Messages {   Name = Daemon   mailcommand = "/usr/lib/bacula/bsmtp -h localhost -f
\"\(Bacula\) \<%r\>\" -s \"Bacula daemon message\" %r"   mail =
root@localhost = all, !skipped               console = all, !skipped,
!saved   append = "/var/lib/bacula/log" = all, !skipped }

# Default pool definition Pool {   Name = Default   Pool Type = Backup   Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle
Volumes   AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes 
Volume Retention = 365 days         # one year }

# File Pool definition Pool {   Name = File   Pool Type = Backup   Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle
Volumes   AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes 
Volume Retention = 365 days         # one year   Maximum Volume Bytes
= 50G          # Limit Volume size to something reasonable   Maximum Volumes = 100               # Limit number of Volumes in Pool }


# Scratch pool definition Pool {   Name = Scratch   Pool Type = Backup }

#
# Restricted console used by tray-monitor to get the status of the director
# Console {   Name = nima-desktop-mon   Password = "-T0h6HCXWYNy0wWqOomysMvRGflQ_TA6c"   CommandACL = status, .status }
```

**bacula-fd.conf on client:**

```
#
# Default  Bacula File Daemon Configuration file
#
#  For Bacula release 5.0.3 (08/05/10) -- Windows MinGW32
#
# There is not much to change here except perhaps the
# File daemon Name
#

#
# "Global" File daemon configuration specifications
#
FileDaemon {                            # this is me
  Name = nimaxp-fd
  FDport = 9102                # where we listen for the director
  WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\Bacula\\working"
  Pid Directory = "C:\\Program Files\\Bacula\\working"
# Plugin Directory = "C:\\Program Files\\Bacula\\plugins"
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 10
}

#
# List Directors who are permitted to contact this File daemon
#
Director {
  Name = Nima-desktop-dir
  Password = "Cv70F6pf1t6pBopT4vQOnigDrR0v3L"
}

#
# Restricted Director, used by tray-monitor to get the
#   status of the file daemon
#
Director {
  Name = nimaxp-mon
  Password = "q5b5g+LkzDXorMViFwOn1/TUnjUyDlg+gRTBp236GrU3"
  Monitor = yes
}

# Send all messages except skipped files back to Director
Messages {
  Name = Standard
  director = Nima-desktop = all, !skipped, !restored
}
```

I have checked my firewall and disabled the firewall but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to wrap the text from the config file, its too jumbled to look at.

Comment: Can you do the following as debugging procedures: 1) Change the director address to the public address instead of the local address and restart Bacula 2) Run bconsole on your server hosting the Bacula director and execute `status <client-name-here>` and report the status of these two commands? And yes, wrap text and make sure your configuration file is legible in the preview - if it isn't, then we can't quite read it easily. I'd say that your question requires a bit more debugging effort from your end. Considering that it's been migrated from StackOverflow, you are excused.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are getting blocked by your firewall.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9101 -j ACCEPT
```